# charm.pool.map & tqdm: obtain a progressbar

Tags: python, tqdm, charm++

I'm using the wanderfull library [charm4py](https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py) to parralelise tasks on a cluster of several machines. I'm just using the function `charm.pool.map`, which is documented [there](https://charm4py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pool.html).

Using the classical `list(tqdm.tqdm(char.pool.map(...),total=...))` did not work: the progressbar was printed but only after the last iteration.

How should i write this ? is it even possible ?

Edit: cross-posted on a charm4py issue there : https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py/issues/178

Comment: `char.pool.map` is blocking, hence why you are only getting the progressbar after the last iteration. I believe you need to use `char.pool.map_async`, but I have yet to understand how to obtain the results as they become ready, so I cannot help you further. I thought `charm.iwait` is the way to go, but I cannot manage to make it work for now...

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway ! If you manage to make something work, please tell me. I'll try a little with `map_async` and if I manage to make it work I'll tell you

Comment: I think the problem is that the Future returned by map_async is not a collection of individual Futures per Task execution; it can only be queried when the iterator given to map_async is fully consumed. It is not like in Ray, where [wait](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/package-ref.html#ray.wait) can return a list of individual futures that are ready, and a list of the remaining non-ready ones.

Comment: So this is hopeless ?

Comment: I don't think it is hopeless, but probably not as trivial as one could hope for.

Comment: Maybe spawning a bunch of `map.pool.Task`s could work ? They will each be a Future. But then, I don't know how to wait asynchronously for each of them.

Comment: Hey, in the code of `charm.pool.map_async`, there https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py/blob/master/charm4py/pool.py , there is a `multi_future` option. This options returns a list of individual futures instead of only one future, like ray's `wait`. Could this work ?

Comment: I think you found the argument we were looking for! I will put as an answer the structure that you need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @lrnv suggestion about `multi_future`, the following code should correctly display the progress of a pool of workers.

```
from charm4py import charm
from tqdm import tqdm

futures = charm.pool.map_async(func, iterable, multi_future=True)
pBar = tqdm(total=len(futures))
for future in charm.iwait(futures):
    # Do something with future.get()
    pBar.update()
```